# Iframe background video not working on some Iphones

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iframe

I am creating a single page website on squarespace and I added a background video using Iframe and grabbing src from vimeo. I have researched and learned that safari does't play videos if they are not muted, so I attempted to mute and added other suggestions like inline but still the video won't play. I have also noticed though that on my friends Iphone 10 it worked, and on someone else's Iphone 10 it didn't? I made sure both had low power mode off so I am not sure if it's my code or if it could be possible settings differences they both have? Here is the Iframe code. Also here is the [squarespace website](https://walrus-shark-jcea.squarespace.com/), password is david. (if you open this on mobile ignore the big font I haven't adjusted size on that yet). Any potential leads or tips would greatly help! I have been going in circles all weekend trying to get to the bottom of this.

`<iframe id="v0" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/318621793?background=1&autoplay=1&loop=1&byline=0&title=0&playsinline=0&muted=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen playsinline autoplay mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen muted >
</iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include most Video.type like mp4, MPEG-4,etc..
For all platform

Comment: ah great suggestion, I will try it and update. Thanks!